# How can i make "date pagination" with wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

i have this code in my wordpress site.

```
$today = date("Y-m-d"); //Today's posts
        $args = array( 
                    'post_type' => 'questions', 
                    'meta_key' => '_question_date', 
                    'posts_per_page' => 20, 
                    'order' => 'DESC',
                    'meta_query' => array(
                        array(
                           'key' => '_question_date',
                           'value' => $today,
                           'compare' => '=',
                           'type' => 'CHAR'
                       )
                    )
 );
```

can i pagination this with custom meta query date? please help me!

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: i was ask this second time. no body didnt see. i just need help. what can i do for this?

Comment: Did you even read the link?

Comment: yes. but my english not perfect. i just understand i wont write "can someone help me" again. it isnt?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Date Pagination plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/date-pagination)
You can use the plugin functions in your theme after installation

**Examples**

These examples show you how to add Date Pagination to pages by seting the date_pagination_type query var.

**Date pagination with pre_get_posts**

You can set the type of date pagination to 'yearly', 'monthly' or 'daily' with the 'date_pagination_type' query variable.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'monthly_paginated_home_query' );
function monthly_paginated_home_query( $query ) {

    // not a wp-admin page and the query is for the main query
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {

        //  on the home page only
        if ( is_home() ) {

            // set the date pagination to 'monthly'
            $query->set('date_pagination_type', 'monthly'); 

            // set other arguments here
        }
    }
}
```

**Date pagination with WP_Query**

You can set the type of date pagination to 'yearly', 'monthly' or 'daily' with the 'date_pagination_type' argument.

In this example we set it to 'monthly'.

```
<?php
// Get the paged variable and use it in the custom query.
// (see: http://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination ).
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

// Example arguments.
$args = array(
    // set the date pagination to monthly
    'date_pagination_type' => 'monthly', // 'yearly', 'monthly', 'daily'
    'paged'                => $paged,
);

// The custom query.
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
<!-- The Loop -->
<?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
<!-- Your theme's loop code here -->
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Your answer awsome but i need list by custom post type's custom date.  like
 ` 'key' => '_question_date',     'value' => $today,`

Comment: no problem
You will write your own query and give the following value to your query array
'date_pagination_type' => 'monthly'
I suggest to see the documentation of the plugin I mentioned

Comment: but its shows 27th and 28th date in same page. i just want see only todays date and tomorrows date. understand? in page url must be "27-01-2018"

Comment: Nice solution ...!

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution. it works very well. i hope this help to others.

```
            $today = date("Y-m-d");
            $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
                if($paged == 1) {
                    $getdate = $today;
                } 
                else if ($paged >= 2) {
                    $date = strtotime("-".$paged+1 ." days");
                    $getdate = date("Y-m-d",$date);
                }
            $args = array( 
                        'post_type' => 'questions', 
                        'meta_key' => '_question_date', 
                        'posts_per_page' => 20, 
                        'order' => 'DESC',
                        'meta_query' => array(
                            array(
                               'key' => '_question_date',
                               'value' => $getdate,
                               'compare' => '=', 
                               'type' => 'CHAR'
                           )
                        )
            );
```